# Animated images on homescreen

Tags: android, ios

I have a client that wants me to make an app that creates animated backgrounds behind the app icons on Homescreen. I said that it's not possible but I just want to be sure that I'm not totally wrong...

It should work on both Android and iOS.

Am I wrong?

Comment: A normal icon, I am pretty sure cannot animate. However, you could make an Icon sized widget. That could do anything you want, including animate.

Comment: Its not the icon, but the background picture... You know the Homescreen and lock screen background image.

Comment: In Android it is quite simple: take a look to live wallpapers. In iOS I am aware of such apps working on jailbreaked devices.

Comment: Thanks! It needs to work on stock iPhones tho. But thanks for in-lighting me.

Comment: Definitely can't do it on ios

Comment: Where you want display animated images either mobile homescreen or app home screen?